# all css files and image are not loading in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Why all css files and images are not getting loaded in cakephp. Although i've written code like this in my `default.ctp`

`echo $html->css('generic');`

Please help me in this issue..

css files are placed in `app\webroot\css`

Comment: In the CSS file, what is the URL that is pointing at the images? if everything works, but the images don't load, it is probably an issue with the way you are pointing at the images in the CSS file. Give us an example of how your pointing at an image in the css file.

Comment: I got a solution,

these changes in my apache htaccess file

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>

and remove comment before
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to copy the .htaccess file into your `htdocs/yourcakeproject/` directory.
If you're running your Cake application on an Apache webserver you have to make sure that the module **[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)** is installed.

If you use Lighttpd as your webserver, there is a chapter in the CakeBook how you have to configure Lighttpd: [Pretty-URLs-and-Lighttpd](http://book.cakephp.org/view/918/Pretty-URLs-and-Lighttpd).

Answer (score 1):

Try this changes.In Apache config File

1.LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
(Enable This Line) by removing #.Next Step is

2.Replace This Code  “AllowOverride None” By  “AllowOverride All”.

Comment: Replacing “AllowOverride None” By “AllowOverride All” solved this problem for me,